# Ajax XHTTP Request wont work

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

i've been stuck on this one for a while please help.

I am trying to perform a XHTTP request, parsing? (is that the right term) a XML document. The request will not enter the myFunction(xml), i dont know why, it is responding 200 ok, so should be fine right?

The request should check the XML for the email entered in the HTML form and respond accordingly if it finds it.

Any help appreciated!!

Javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadDoc()
{
email = document.getElementById('email');
password = document.getElementById('password');

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        myFunction(xhttp);
    }
}
}
xhttp.open("POST", "customer.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) 
{
var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
txt = "";
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("email");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (x[i].nodeValue == document.getElementById('email')) 
    {
        return (true);
        alert('Success, you have logged in!');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Failed to log in');
        document.myForm.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
 }
}

</script>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
<customer>
  <custid />
  <firstname />
  <lastname />
  <email />
  <password />
  <phone />
</customer>
<customer>
  <custid>562b5d237b599</custid>
  <firstname>1</firstname>
  <lastname>1</lastname>
  <email>1</email>
  <password>1</password>
  <phone>1</phone>
</customer>
<customer>
  <custid>562b62824e3f7</custid>
  <firstname>ben</firstname>
  <lastname>1</lastname>
  <email>1</email>
  <password>1</password>
  <phone>1</phone>
</customer>
<customer>
   <custid>562b63224b80f</custid>
  <firstname>ben</firstname>
  <lastname>ben</lastname>
  <email>ben@gmail.com</email>
  <password>ben</password>
  <phone>0266746374</phone>
</customer>
<customer>
  <custid>562b68ea06ed1</custid>
  <firstname>mark</firstname>
  <lastname>mark</lastname>
  <email>mark@gmail.com</email>
  <password>mark</password>
  <phone />
 </customer>
 </customers>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle link for your code? Wanted to look at your customer.xml.

And check what you are seeing in the developer console's network tab as response.

Comment: did you mean to pass the XML data provided by `xhttp.responseText`? Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest for learning how to use the `XMLHttpRequest` API. You will need to serialize your retrieved text as XML too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/usgqcven/2/ Dont know how to use fiddle so i posted the XML in the CSS area... also i will edit it into above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> }
> xhttp.open("POST", "customer.xml", true);
> xhttp.send();
> ```

Here you try to use `xhttp` **outside** the function in which you create it. Watch where you put your `}`s (being more careful about how you indent your code would make this more obvious).

> ```
> x[i].nodeValue == document.getElementById('email')
> ```

That is never going to be true. `getElementById` will return an HTML Element Node, not a string. Presumably you are looking for `.value`.

When you debug your code you need to examine the values you are testing to see if they actually match.

> ```
> else
> {
>     alert('Failed to log in');
>     document.myForm.email.focus();
>     return false;
> }
> ```

and here, if the first node value doesn't match, then you immediately `return` so you don't test any of the others.

You need to put the condition for failure *outside* the loop so it only triggers if you get no matches.

---

This system is, of course, *completely insecure*, since anyone can request the XML file and read the passwords in it.

Comment: Sorry i didnt read your answer properly, Thank you that works well. But i am unable to get it to match email against XML. Is this code correct?        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    { 
        if (x[i].value == document.getElementById('email')) 
        {
         alert('Success, you have logged in!');
            return (true);
        }
     alert('Failed to log in');
     document.myForm.email.focus();
     return false;
    }